Как использовать Hibernate в самописной библиотеке Java?
Я пишу свою библиотеку, в которой нужно хранить данные в БД. Для этого использую Hibernate. Подключаю библиотеку к стороннему приложению, где уже открыто соединение Hibernate, через jar. Во время транзакций внутри библиотеки, связанных с моими сущностями, получаю ошибку:
org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'CustomVector'

Предполагаю, что Hibernate не видит сущностей из библиотек, поскольку в БД также не создались таблицы, связанные с ними. Отмечу, что моя БД никак не связана сущностями с БД в приложении, все спроектировано автономно.
Работа с Hibernate производится через аннотации типа @Entity у основных классов, а также через DAO-классы. Соединение осуществляю через EntityManagerFactory и EntityManager, они приходят из внешнего приложения в библиотеку.
Каким образом можно подключить библиотеку к существующему в другом приложении соединению с БД, чтобы в дальнейшем библиотека могла работать со своими данными там? Или как это можно обойти, чтобы библиотека могла хранить свои данные где-то и затем подгружать и обновлять их по мере надобности?
Один из классов:
@Entity
@Table(name="custom_profile")
public class CustomVector {
    @Id
    @Column(name="vector_id")
    private int vector_id;
    // ...
}

Запрос, на который приходит ошибка:
FROM CustomVector WHERE vector_id = 2


Непонятна суть вопроса. Вопросы писать надо вдумчиво и разборчиво, чтобы можно было понять другим. Из того, что написано явно видно что ошибка возникает неслучайно, потому что отсутствует таблица.

@RomanC, почему может не создаваться таблица? Если я создаю некоторую "демо"-версию приложения, где весь код представлен не в сторонней библиотеке, а внутри приложения, то все работает. Таблицы создаются. А если подключаю тот же код в виде библиотеки к другому приложению, которое уже работает с Hibernate, создаёт свои таблицы в своей БД, то мои таблицы из библиотеки не создаются, хотя соединение передается в библиотеку корректно. Может есть какие-то особенности реализации Hibernate в библиотеке?

Я же уже сказал, что отсутствует таблица, что непонятно? На вопрос отвечать невозможно. Учи как задавать вопросы здесь.
